# filtering arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript

Below is my code i want to filter based on what the user inputs. for example if user inputs 3 then all hotels with a star rating of 3 and above should be displayed. I dont know how to do this.

```
class Hotel {
constructor(name, stars, distance, wifi, pool, price){
this.name = name;
this.stars = stars;
this.distance = distance;
    this.wifi = wifi;
    this.pool = pool;
    this.price = price;
 }
}

var hotels=[];
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Grand", "5","0.5","yes","no","190"));
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Plaza", "4","1","yes","yes","70") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Lord Miliburn", "4","5","yes","no","65") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Grange", "3","1","yes","no","57") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Windmill", "1","10","no","no","5") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Excel", "3","0.5","yes","no","56") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Ritz", "2","5","yes","no","14") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Victoria", "4","0.5","yes","no","80") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("Pheonix House", "4","1","yes","No","72") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Lodge", "2","1","no","no","25") );
hotels.push(new Hotel("The Sanctum", "5","2","yes","yes","180") );


const userStar = prompt("What would you like the minimum hotel star rating, 
 to be?");
  const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function(hotels){


   if(hotels.stars>=4){
   return true;

 }
return false;

 })
console.log(matchingStars);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to `userStar` inside `filter` callback:

```
const userStar = prompt("What would you like the minimum hotel star rating, to be?");
const matchingStars = hotels.filter(function(hotel){
   return hotel.stars >= userStar;
});
console.log(matchingStars);
```

[Demofiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y08kbL6b/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
userStar = parseInt (userStar)
```

To convert the string to integer, add this code. Because thé input returning a string by default..
 And compare:

```
hotels.stars >= userStar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of array.

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

**DEMO**

```js
const hotels = [{
  "name": "The Grand",
  "stars": "5",
  "distance": "0.5",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "no",
  "price": "190"
}, {
  "name": "The Plaza",
  "stars": "4",
  "distance": "1",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "yes",
  "price": "70"
}, {
  "name": "The Lord Miliburn",
  "stars": "4",
  "distance": "5",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "no",
  "price": "65"
}, {
  "name": "The Grange",
  "stars": "3",
  "distance": "1",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "no",
  "price": "57"
}, {
  "name": "The Windmill",
  "stars": "1",
  "distance": "10",
  "wifi": "no",
  "pool": "no",
  "price": "5"
}, {
  "name": "The Excel",
  "stars": "3",
  "distance": "0.5",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "no",
  "price": "56"
}, {
  "name": "The Ritz",
  "stars": "2",
  "distance": "5",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "no",
  "price": "14"
}, {
  "name": "The Victoria",
  "stars": "4",
  "distance": "0.5",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "no",
  "price": "80"
}, {
  "name": "Pheonix House",
  "stars": "4",
  "distance": "1",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "No",
  "price": "72"
}, {
  "name": "The Lodge",
  "stars": "2",
  "distance": "1",
  "wifi": "no",
  "pool": "no",
  "price": "25"
}, {
  "name": "The Sanctum",
  "stars": "5",
  "distance": "2",
  "wifi": "yes",
  "pool": "yes",
  "price": "180"
}];

function onSearch() {
  let value = document.querySelector('#stars').value
  if (!value) {
    alert('Please enter value.')
    return false;

  }
  console.log(hotels.filter(o => {
    return o.stars >= value
  }))
}
```

```html
<input id="stars" type="number" /><button onclick="onSearch(this)">search</button>
```